# Passing value to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

does an empty text box pass an empty value to the database ** SQL server 2008** or an empty

string

**i am using string.empty method before saving the data** cause i need to clear the data

before the user inputs anything

i am not allowing nulls in my table but the passed value by the text box seems to be passed

as " " not as null so the table is accepting that value and I don't want that to happen

Answer (score 0):

You could set the textbox value to `null` instead op `String.Empty`

It's also recommended to check the input before adding it to the database. Like so:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTextbox.Text))
    //No value
```